# Is it possible to change the index of an item in a list in AWS s3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use a bucket in aws s3 to store the images of a carousel, and the customer needed to be able to modify the order of displaying the images. Is there any method that makes it possible to modify the indexes of this list?

I intend to transform the current listing into a drag and drop list, where the user would be able to modify the display order of the carousel images by dragging them. When the image assumed the new position, trigger a method that made the corresponding change in the s3 bucket.

About how I'm uploading and listing the images:  I store the images in s3 using the "AWS.S3.ManagedUpload" upload method; And to list I use "s3.listObjects". When I list images the order of the list is always from oldest to newest image. It would be this ordering that I wanted to be able to dynamically change. I researched the other s3 methods but I didn't find any that allow me to "sort" the bucket.

Edit: I forgot to mention a very important detail: I have two platforms, one is for the end user (where the carousel is displayed), the other is the admin dashboard, the idea is that Adm can change the order of the images displayed on the dashboard in the end user.

Comment: Where are you storing the index? What is the index exactly? Just a list in your JavaScript code? It is extremely unclear how you are storing a index of images in your S3 bucket. The S3 bucket should be storing the image files themselves, any sort of dynamic indexing of those files should be done in some sort of database.

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't be clear! I store the images in s3 using the "AWS.S3.ManagedUpload" upload method; And to list I use "s3.listObjects". When I list images the order of the list is always from oldest to newest image. It would be this ordering that I wanted to be able to dynamically change. I researched the other s3 methods but I didn't find any that allow me to "sort" the bucket.

Comment: `s3.listObjects` doesn't guarantee oldest to newest. And relying on that API for your index, while also expecting to be able to modify the ordering, is completely unreasonable.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: As I suggested in my first comment, store the list of images, in the order you want them to appear, in a database.

Answer (score 2):

This is no way to control the order of existing objects returned by ListObjects or ListObjectsV2. From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html

> List results are always returned in UTF-8 binary order

So when you say

> When I list images the order of the list is always from oldest to newest image

it makes me suspect that the keys have the datetime of the upload in them(?)

I think usually you would have to store the indexes of the images somewhere separate to the images themselves. Traditionally, in a database... but if you want an S3-only solution, you could store them in a separate JSON object alongside the images?

Comment: Hmm, got it. Yes, that's right, there is a timestamp that is used when the upload is done. I'll try your solution, then I'll come back to tell you how it turned out, thanks!